# I don't understand this behaviour in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I would like to access the value of the second unique element in an integer vector using Rcpp, but instead I get a vector of zeros that is equal in length to the value of the second item in the integer vector. What am I doing wrong?

```
require(Rcpp)
cppFunction("NumericVector test(IntegerVector labelling1) {
  IntegerVector lvls = unique(labelling1);
  return(lvls[1]);
}")

  test(1:5)
 #[1] 0 0
```

Comment: I think I was asking it to return a NumericVector not an int so when it coerces an int to a numeric vector this is the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a separate issue here: you are trying to construct a `NumericVector` from an `int`, and Rcpp does the following:

1. The integer value `2` is being returned by your function,
2. A `NumericVector` is constructed as `NumericVector(2)`; ie, a `NumericVector` with length 2.

If what you really want is an `IntegerVector` representing the value at that index, you must write:

```
IntegerVector test(IntegerVector labelling1) {
  IntegerVector lvls = unique(labelling1);
  return IntegerVector::create(lvls[1]);
}
```

Or you could also do, using Rcpp attributes (which handles conversion from `int` to `IntegerVector` automatically for you):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test(IntegerVector labelling1) {
  IntegerVector lvls = unique(labelling1);
  return lvls[1];
}

/*** R
test(1:5)
*/
```

Comment: I am very new to C++ and Rcpp but it seems to me that almost no one would want this type of conversion from ``int`` to ``NumericVector`` -- would it be sensible or practical  to yield an error or warning when a user tries to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Subsetting sugar expects an `IntegerVector` as index (http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/subsetting/). If you want to mimic R's `unique` function you need some additional changes:

```
cppFunction("IntegerVector  test(IntegerVector labelling1, int i) {
              // get sorted unique values
              IntegerVector lvls = sort_unique(labelling1);
              // get unique values in order of occurence 
              IntegerVector lvls1 = lvls[match(lvls, labelling1) - 1];
              return(lvls1[IntegerVector::create(i - 1)]);}")

test(c(5:1, 1L), 2)
#[1] 4
```

Comment: Obviously, there are more efficient possibilities to find the second unique element.

Comment: Thank you. (I agree there are more efficient ways of finding the second unique element, but it was a minimal example that replicated my problem).